# donePicker unrecognized selector sent to instance UiTextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, toolbar

I'm simply adding a done toolbar on keyboard for `UiTextField`

On done clicked I'm facing to
`unrecognized selector sent to instance` error :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

        self.addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()
    }
   
    @IBOutlet weak var betTextField: UITextField!

func addDoneButtonOnKeyboard(){
        let doneToolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50))
        doneToolbar.barStyle = .default

        let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let done: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(BetViewController.doneAction))

        let items = [flexSpace, done]
        doneToolbar.items = items
        doneToolbar.sizeToFit()
        
        betTextField.inputAccessoryView = doneToolbar
    }

    @objc func doneAction() {
        betTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
```

The `BetViewController` is added by StoryBoardID.

What am I missing ?

Error message :

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Bet.BetViewController betTexField:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffa0c860e00'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 732.18.6 - Device: iPhone 12 Pro Max (4549AD60-8D64-44E7-B2D6-C347655A1DA6) - Runtime: iOS 14.3 (18C61) - DeviceType: iPhone 12 Pro Max
```

Comment: Is this code inside `BetViewController`? If so, try changing your action to `#selector(self.doneAction)`

Comment: Yes it is .  Same error with self.

Comment: Full error message? It would provide more infos.

Comment: *"The `BetViewController` is added by StoryBoardID"* --- added how? Are you keeping it in memory?

Comment: simply added this way " self.present(betViewController, animated: true, completion: nil) " from the main view controller

Comment: Are you sure you connected betTextField  to storyboard 'ReferencingOutlets' ?

Comment: @OmerTekbiyik  yes it is , just checked

Comment: Did you have a method named `betTextField` with one parameter? Remove that link. But you see, now with the error, we see it's not related to `doneAction()`

Answer (score 0):

In StoryBoard I had a Sent Event " Editing Did End " not used that I just removed.

There is no conflicts with the Done ToolBar anymore.